# TailwindCss Not Responsive to Screen Size

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="sm:text-center">
      <h1>
        Hello
      </h1>
    </div>
  
  );
}

export default App;
```

**tailwind.js**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [],
  presets: [],
  darkMode: 'media', // or 'class'
  theme: {
    screens: {
      sm: '640px',
      md: '768px',
      lg: '1024px',
      xl: '1280px',
      '2xl': '1536px',
    },
```

I'm expecting for the text to be aligned to the left by default and on screens 640px and above text should be centered. However the text stays aligned to the left. I do have the html meta tag for responsiveness on my index.html file '

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Debug it. Consider a red background `div` element and use `sm:hidden`. It works?

Comment: Can you try removing custom screens from tailwind.config.js? I think the problem lies there, and don't forget to restart localhost after changing the config file. I remember adding custom screen to this module, and it wouldn't work when it came to responsive breakpoints, it could be Tailwind's bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because I left the content array empty. I had to configure the path to any file that contained tailwind class names.

Which is a little weird because other class names seemed to work just not the breakpoints. But that did solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it only activates when its 640px and below. Plus your small media query should be around 360px